# Apply the same function to multiple jQuery objects without reselct them

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I use to declare all the objects I need at the top of my functions, which I use to cache and keep the app fast. For example I have something like:

```
var $object1 = $('#my_element'),
    $object2 = $('.other_elements'),
    $object3 = $('.again_something_else');
```

I use those variables in the code individually, so for example `$object1.doSomething()` or `$object2.doElse()` but in some scenarios I need to apply the same function to two or more already selected variables. There is a way to merge those variables together, to avoid re-selecting of the elements I need?

I would avoid this:

```
 $('#my_element, .other_elements').myFunction()
```

and reuse the variables I have already.

Comment: Isn't that what `.each()` does?

Comment: the each in jQuery is implicit, and I would like to merge the objects together.

Comment: $.each([$object1,$object2], function(index, val) { val.myFunction(); });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

So if you wanted to combine `$object1` and `$object2`, you could:

```
var $one_and_two = $object1.add($object2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DHJvR/1/

`add` doesn't modify anything, it simply merges the selected elements into a new jQuery object and returns it so `$x.add(...)` won't do anything to `$object1` (thanks to [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) for the reminder/correction on this point).

Comment: I don't understand the odd looking of this method: what if I do: `var $one_and_two = $($object1).add($object2);` ?

Comment: @mimo: That should work pretty much the same.

Comment: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method." There is no need to create a new empty jQuery object.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Right, thanks for the reminder. For some reason I though `$x.add(...)` modified `$x`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) to merge the element cache together, because they are essentially arrays.

```
jQuery.merge($object1, $object2).myFunction();
```

Do note that `$object1` will contain the merged list, so you will not be able to re-use the cache. You can avoid that by:

```
$.merge( $.merge([], $object1), $object2);
```

---

IMO, I think it would be simpler to do this:

```
function assignHandler () {
    $object1.myFunction();
    $object2.myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Description: Merge the contents of two arrays together into the first array.

Comment: `$.merge`: `Returns: Array`